# Is there a way to use decorators to bind a route to azure WebPubSub events using azure functions using the V2 Python programming model?

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-web-pubsub

Azure functions recently changed their programming model for python as described here,
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-compute-blog/azure-functions-v2-python-programming-model/ba-p/3665168 and I am trying to port some code.

In v1 you use function.json to bind get the connection as an input, as well as to listen to messages from the hub.

```
{
"scriptFile": "__init__.py",
"bindings": [
    {
        "type": "webPubSubTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "name": "request",
        "hub": "simplechat",
        "eventName": "message",
        "eventType": "user"
    }
]
}
```

In C# and V2 for python, you should use decorators https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-web-pubsub/reference-functions-bindings.md but as far as I can tell, there is no decorator for this in Python.

Comment: can you share the python code that which you tried?

Comment: Have you tried your python code in Azure function V3?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say the https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-compute-blog/azure-functions-v2-python-programming-model/ba-p/3665168 v2 python programming model. 

In the new model decorators are used to bind parameters rather than function.json but i cant find a decorator for webpub sub.

Comment: The code im experimenting with is here https://github.com/Gobaan/chatwithfriends/tree/remove_user_id but it doesn't have the webpubsub trigger, since I cannot find a decorator for that.

Answer (score -1):

- I used Azure functions version(v3) and python version 3.10.9.
- In v2 I tried using my python code but unable to reach so switched to v3 then Iam able to bind and connected. Please refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=v4&pivots=programming-language-python) for versions info
- I used the below decorators to bind a route to Azure Web PubSub events using Azure Functions v2.

```
import azure.functions as func

def webpubsub_route(route: str):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(req: func.WebPubSubEvent):
            return func(req)

        wrapper.route = route
        return wrapper

    return decorator

@webpubsub_route(route="myhub/mymessage")
def main(event: func.WebPubSubEvent):
    message = event.get_json()
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Received message: {message}", status_code=200)
```

- `webpubsub_event`decorator logs the incoming event details and passes the event request to the `main` function for further processing.

[image]

- Able to access the response from the hub by inputs given from userID.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What package did you use to get the WebPubSubEvent, its not part of my azure.functions package. But I am unsure that you are using python V2.

The code should not have any function.json files